# java String becomes null when new instance is created

Tags: java, string, null

I am stuck with this problem for ages in the following code.
Basically, the `String` becomes `null` when a new instance of an object is created.
For example,

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    //Yahoo Weather Code London
    setCitySelected("44418");
    System.out.println(new CityChange().getCitySelected()); // print null
    // System.out.println(getCitySelected()) print 44418
  }
});
```

Is there any way to fix this problem? Because I have to call `getCitySelected()` in a different class that it returns `null` value just like above.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will benefit greatly from reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: Why are you creating a new CityChange instead of using the one you have already configured?

Comment: @LouisWasserman the above code is just an example. What I need to do is to call `getCitySelected()` in a different class.

Comment: Then you need to be passing in the CityChange object you called setCitySelected on, not creating a new one.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what do you mean by that? any example?

Comment: i think there is a problem about `understanding object and it properties life cycle` unless `CitySelected` is static

Comment: Your "different class" needs to have a CityChange variable passed in either in its constructor or with a setter method.  Two classes shouldn't "magically communicate," you have to explicitly pass data from one to the other.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have created a getter and setter method for the `String citySelected`. Is it a must that I have to pass a variable via Constructor?

Comment: It is not citySelected that needs a getter and setter, but the CityChange must be passed to the other class, either with a setter or in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I don't know the scope of `setCitySelected("44418")` method. If this method is in `CityChange` object then first create the `new` Instance of this class, using this instance you set and get the value.

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    CityChange cc = new CityChange()
    cc.setCitySelected("44418");
    System.out.println(cc.getCitySelected()); // should print 44418
  }
});
```

.

```
Basically, the String becomes null when a new instance of an object is created.
```

Whenever you create a new object of the class, all the values in object will be null unless you don't set any values.

Comment: however, when I am trying to call the method `getCitySelected` I will need to make a `new` instance. Will there be any way around that?